# Scraping zip files from website in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to scrape data from [this page](http://mis.ercot.com/misapp/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=13060&reportTitle=Historical%20DAM%20Load%20Zone%20and%20Hub%20Prices&showHTMLView=&mimicKey). I don't know where to start, as I've never worked with scraping or automating downloads in Python, but I'm just trying to find a way to automate downloading all the files on the linked page (and others like it -- just using this one as an example).

There is no discernible pattern in the file names linked; they appear to be random numbers that reference an ID-file name lookup table elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for above URL provided you could download zip files by following the below code:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

hostname="http://mis.ercot.com"
r = requests.get(f'{hostname}/misapp/GetReports.do?reportTypeId=13060&reportTitle=Historical%20DAM%20Load%20Zone%20and%20Hub%20Prices&showHTMLView=&mimicKey')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
regex = re.compile('.*misdownload/servlets/mirDownload.*')
atgs=soup.findAll("a",{"href":regex})
for link in atgs:
    data=requests.get(f"{hostname}{link['href']}")
    filename=link["href"].split("doclookupId=")[1][:-1]+".zip"
    with open(filename,"wb") as savezip:
        savezip.write(data.content)
    print(filename,"Saved")
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)